# Unable to run SQL Server 2019 docker with volumes and get ERROR: Setup FAILED copying system data file

Tags: sql-server, docker

When I run latest sql server image from [official documentation](http://docker%20run%20-e%20%27ACCEPT_EULA=Y%27%20-e%20%27MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=%3CYourStrong!Passw0rd%3E%27%20-p%201433:1433%20-v%20%3Chost%20directory%3E/data:/var/opt/mssql/data%20-v%20%3Chost%20directory%3E/log:/var/opt/mssql/log%20-v%20%3Chost%20directory%3E/secrets:/var/opt/mssql/secrets%20-d%20mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest) on linux host.

`docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=asdasdasdsad' -p 1433:1433 -v ./data:/var/opt/mssql/data -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest`

I get error:

```
ERROR: Setup FAILED copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\model_replicatedmaster.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/model_replicatedmaster.mdf':  5(Access is denied.)
```

This message occurs only on Linux host and with binded volumes.

Answer (score 37):

I happen because lack of permission. On 2019 mssql docker move from root user images into not-root. It made that docker sql-server containers with binded volumes and run on Linux host has a permission issue (=> has no permission to write into binded volume).

There are few solution for this problem:

#### 1. Run docker as root.

eg. compose:

```yaml
version: '3.6'
services:
  mssql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    user: root
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=BLAH
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/opt/mssql/data
```

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/13#issuecomment-641904197

#### 2. Setup proper directory owner (mssql)

1. Check id for mssql user on docker image
   `sudo docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server id mssql`
   gives: `uid=10001(mssql) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)`
2. Change folder's owner
   `sudo chown 10001 VOLUME_DIRECTORY`

Source in Spanish: https://www.eiximenis.dev/posts/2020-06-26-sql-server-docker-no-se-ejecuta-en-root/

#### 3. Give a full access (not recommended)

Give full access to db files on host
`sudo chmod 777 -R VOLUME_DIRECTORY`

Comment: What if I don't have a 'mssql' user on my host?

Comment: @Nico the `mssql` user is not on the host but in the image ...

Comment: They should have done this better. On one side, 2019 changes running user from root to non-root, and on the other side there's blocking issue caused by this change and requires manual actions to fix.

Comment: Thx @GetoX , option 2 was a great solution

Comment: Option 2 saved my day

Comment: If MS guys did this, shouldn't we avoid mounted volumes?

Answer (score 4):

I encountered a similar problem while attempting to set up SQL Server with Dockers on a Linux Server.

To address the problem, please consult the documentation ([MS SQL Server Docker Storage Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-docker-container-security?view=sql-server-ver16#storagepermissions)) for guidance on resolving the issue. The issue pertains to the lack of write permissions for the Docker container user on the host filesystem.

You can follow the instructions provided by [@GetoX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65601078/13941207) to rectify the problem. It is worth noting that [@somethingRandom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75144309/2103854) is also correct, but his solution requires file permissions to be set to 777 in order to work effectively.

**docker-compose.yaml section for mssql server**

```
mssql:
    container_name: mssql
    hostname: xxxxxx
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    volumes:
        - ./mssql/data:/var/opt/mssql/data
        - ./mssql/log:/var/opt/mssql/log
        - ./mssql/secrets:/var/opt/mssql/secrets
    ports:
        - 1433:1433
    environment:
        - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
        - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=xxxxx
        - MSSQL_PID=Express
    networks:
        - default
    restart: unless-stopped
    healthcheck:
        test:
            [
                "CMD-SHELL",
                "/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P xxxxxx -Q 'SELECT 1' || exit 1"
            ]
        interval: 10s
        retries: 10
        start_period: 10s
        timeout: 3s
```

Before building the container, you must create the necessary directories and set appropriate permissions for them to ensure successful operation.

**Linux Host Terminal**

```
   > mkdir -p mssql/data
   > mkdir -p mssql/log
   > mkdir -p mssql/secrets
   > ls -ll  //checks current permissions
   > chgrp -R 0 mssql  //Added the root group to directories
   > chmod -R g=u mssql
   > chown -R 10001:0 mssql  //added non-root user to directories
```

This solution addresses the problem of lacking write access to host directories for the Docker mssql user.

Answer (score 2):

I encoutered the same problem as you trying to run a container based on sql server on DigitalOcean. `user: root` also solved the issue.

Comment: Your solution is a subset of previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the only way I found to fix this issue involves a few manual steps.

I used the following `docker-compose` file for this to work

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  mssql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    platform: linux
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=<testPASSWORDthatISlongENOUGH_1234>
    volumes:
      - ./mssql/data:/var/opt/mssql/data
      - ./backups:/var/backups
```

(the data directory has to be mounted directly due to another issue with SQL server containers hosted on Windows machines)

Then you need to perform the following manual steps:

1. Connect to the database using [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)
2. Find and select your `.bak` database backup file
3. Open a terminal in the container
4. In the directory that the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files are going to be created, `touch` files with the database name you are going to use

```
touch /var/opt/mssql/data/DATABASE_NAME.mdf
touch /var/opt/mssql/data/DATABASE_NAME_log.ldf
```

5. Toggle the option to replace any existing database with the restore

[image]

6. Restore your database

I tried to follow the instructions in this https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/using-volumes-in-sql-server-2019-non-root-containers article but I could not get it to work.

This problem was also discussed in [this](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/7259) github issue (which the bot un-helpfully closed without a proper solution).

Answer (score 1):

Based on [@GetoX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65601078/13941207) Response you only need to set the user used by the mssql server to root.

In your docker run command add the following option (--user) with argument (root) like so (I'm using podman, but it works for docker too):

```
podman run --user root -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=MSSQLServer.1234' -p 1433:1433 -v /root/podman/mssql/2022-latest/data:/var/opt/mssql/data -v /root/podman/mssql/2022-latest/log:/var/opt/mssql/log -v /root/podman/mssql/2022-latest/secrets:/var/opt/mssql/secrets -d --name mssqlserver-2022 mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
```

Comment: You should never use the Root user in Linux for security reasons. It is recommended that you use non-root users with sudo privileges. The reason why Microsoft has used non-root user and sets the ownership in the mssql directory to that user and any directories on the host machine needs to have their ownership changed to that user in order to write that directory. The configuration [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76241280/2103854) I have outlined is the best approach and is recommended solution from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I had success using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

ENV SA_PASSWORD <testPASSWORDthatISlongENOUGH_1234>
ENV ACCEPT_EULA Y

# If we use volumes, the owner of this directory
# is root.  So we need to set them to mssql, but
# at this point they do not yet exist.
# Create the directory first, and set the permissions.
USER root
RUN mkdir -p /var/opt/mssql/data
RUN chown -R mssql: /var/opt/mssql/data

USER mssql
```

Answer (score 0):

Inn case of recent mssql versions, you can run as root, change files ownership and restart as mssql user.

Ex:

```bash
# https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server
$ docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest

# run container as "root"
$ docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" \
    --user root \
    -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=P@55w0rD" \
    -e "MSSQL_PID=Developer" \
    -e 'TZ=America/NewYork'\
    -p 1433:1433  \
    -v local-mssql-data:/var/opt/mssql/data \
    -v local-mssql-log:/var/opt/mssql/log \
    -v local-mssql-secrets:/var/opt/mssql/secrets \
    --name mssql \
    --hostname mssql \
    -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest

# go yo container and fix perms
$ docker exec -it mssql bash
root@mssql:/# chown -R mssql:root /var/opt/mssql/

# stop root container
$ docker stop mssql
$ docker rm mssql

# start container as non-root user
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" \
    -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=P@55w0rD" \
    -e "MSSQL_PID=Developer" \
    -e 'TZ=America/NewYork'\
    -p 1433:1433  \
    -v local-mssql-data:/var/opt/mssql/data \
    -v local-mssql-log:/var/opt/mssql/log \
    -v local-mssql-secrets:/var/opt/mssql/secrets \
    --rm \
    --name mssql \
    --hostname mssql \
    -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
```