# Cannot start Docker SQL Server container on MacOS

Tags: macos, docker

I'm trying to run SQL Server on my Mac using Docker.  I've been able to get this working using the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/tutorial-restore-backup-in-sql-server-container?view=sql-server-ver15

I have gotten everything working except that when I try to start my SQL container in the Docker interface I get the errors pictured below:

```
SQL Server 2019 will run as non-root by default.

This container is running as user mssql.

To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.

2021-12-23 21:50:01.36 Server      Setup step is copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\master.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf'.

2021-12-23 21:50:01.56 Server      ERROR: Setup FAILED copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\master.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf':  5(Access is denied.)

SQL Server 2019 will run as non-root by default.

    This container is running as user mssql.
    
    To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.
    
    2021-12-23 21:52:29.53 Server      Setup step is copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\master.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf'.
    
    2021-12-23 21:52:29.68 Server      ERROR: Setup FAILED copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\master.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf':  5(Access is denied.)
    
    
    ERROR: BootstrapSystemDataDirectories() failure (HRESULT 0x80070005)
    
    ERROR: BootstrapSystemDataDirectories() failure (HRESULT 0x80070005)
```

I am creating my SQL container using this script:

`sudo docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e ‘SA_PASSWORD=password’ --name SQLDev2K19 -h SQLDev2K19 -p 1401:1433 -v SQLDev2K19Data:/var/opt/mssql/data -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest`
The container gets created and attempts to start, but then stops.

However if I use this command the container gets created and starts without any issues and I'm able to connect to the instance using Azure Studio (note that the only difference is that I have not provided the volume flag).
`sudo docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e ‘SA_PASSWORD=password’ --name SQLDev2K19 -h SQLDev2K19 -p 1401:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest`
I have tried the suggestions here, specifically option 2 (I do not want to use root): [Unable to run SQL Server 2019 docker with volumes and get ERROR: Setup FAILED copying system data file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65601077/unable-to-run-sql-server-2019-docker-with-volumes-and-get-error-setup-failed-co)

What am I missing?

Once I'm able to get my SQL container running then I'll be able to attach a back database using the following command:
`docker exec -it slqcontainername mkdir /var/opt/mssql/backup`

Right now if I try that command I get this:
`Error response from daemon: Container 404e44b89d8c33ed6f2596fe57bc55ff5459650801c0b0070a05b79e4be0bb1c is not running`

Comment: what are the permissions for you host folder (ie `SQLDev2K19Data`)?

Comment: A few things to try, if only to give you or other readers ideas: does the server start up OK if you drop the volume parameter? (I appreciate that is not very useful as a final solution, but it might help pinpoint the source of the permission issue). Also, is there a difference if you use an on-host volume rather than a container volume?

Comment: Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Ah, I just re-read your question, and notice that you have tried not using a volume. Try an on-host volume next - I don't know if it will change anything, but perhaps it is worth a go.

Comment: Also, could you just launch a simple image (e.g. Ubuntu) and connect it to the container volume, so you can run an appropriate `chmod` inside the container volume?

Comment: Not sure how to do an on-host volume or simple image.  I'm new to docker containers as of a day ago, but I'll search and read through the docs.  Any suggestions will be helpful.