# Docker on MacOs running SQL Server can't see /var/opt/mssql/backup when trying to restore backup file

Tags: sql-server, docker, azure-data-studio

I've setup docker on my mac and setup a SqlServer container that is running successfully.  I want to restore a backup database file that is currently located in `/var/opt/mssql/backup`.

I follow these steps to restore the file when I connect to my container instance using Azure data studio:

- launch the restore database from backup option by right clicking my instance and selecting `Manage`
- I try to navigate to `/var/opt/mssql/backup` to select my backup file.

There is no backup directory in the Azure studio dialog even though I have confirmed that the directory and backup file exist using the terminal.

What is going on?  How can I access my backup file from Azure data studio and restore it?

Comment: Your backup is located in /var/opt/mssql/backup in MacOs ? So you need to bind that directory on docker container

Comment: I figured as much based on searching and running into a similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70467757/docker-on-macos-running-sql-server-cant-see-var-opt-mssql-backup-when-trying-t.  However, that does not seem to work for me.  When I create my container instance using the -v flag and provide the binding like this: `-v /var/opt/mssql/data:/var/opt/mssql/data` my instance fails to start and I have the error I have posted about here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70467134/cannot-start-docker-sql-server-container-on-mac-os#70467134.  So I'm stuck in a catch 22.

Comment: Specifying `-v /var/opt/mssql/data:/var/opt/mssql/data` is saying `-v localHostPath:containerPath`, and the localHostPath either has to exist already or has to be in a place where you have permissions to create it (without sudo tricks). On macOS the `/var` folder is owned by `root:admin` which is why it failed to create `/var/opt/mssql/data` for you.

Comment: Ok. The localhost path exists.  I did give permissions to the mssql user on the mssql folder as suggested in the second option here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65601077/unable-to-run-sql-server-2019-docker-with-volumes-and-get-error-setup-failed-co.  Or am I supposed to give the permission on the var folder?

Comment: My mssql user has the same permissions as root on the mssql folder, but still I get a permission denied error in docker.  How can I get my mssql user to have the proper permissions for this to work?

Comment: The `mssql` user is inside the container image, not part of the host operating system, so that advice is not effective. The reason sudo tricks don't work with Docker Desktop either is because you're running the CLI tool with sudo and it doesn't actually do any of the work itself - it just passes parameters through to com.docker.backend process which is running with your normal account privileges (i.e.: without sudo). Create the host folder somewhere you actually have access to, e.g.: `mkdir ~/Docker/mssql` and then you can `-v ~/Docker/mssql:/var/opt/mssql` to bind mount that folder.

Comment: Ok. I did that and it worked.  I'm not sure why this is not covered in the documentation.  Unless I missed it.