# Is there a way to set the file permissions when a database backup file is created in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linux, t-sql, ubuntu

I'm currently running Microsoft SQL Server 2022 Express Edition in a Docker container on Ubuntu. I'm running the following query using C# with the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient namespace:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [DBName] TO DISK = N'/path/to/dir/DBName.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = 'DBName', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10;
```

The backup is successfully created with the following permissions:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root root 16900096 Feb 2 11:14 DBName.bak
```

Is there a way I can configure SQL Server to write the backup file with certain permissions (basically the equivalent of running `sudo chmod` on the file)? I specifically want all users to have read/write/execute permissions.

I COULD just have my code run a shell script that sets the permissions after the file is created, but I would prefer a platform-independent solution. I was hoping that SQL Server may have some way of configuring the backup file output.

Comment: Is this a backup file inside the container? It shouldn't be `root:root` unless you've used `USER root` in your Dockerfile and forgotten to switch it back. The default user in mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server images for SQL Server 2017 and beyond is the `mssql` user.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I set the user to root in my docker compose file because of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65601077/unable-to-run-sql-server-2019-docker-with-volumes-and-get-error-setup-failed-co). I just followed the steps in this post and now my backups are being written with the following permissions: `-rw-r----- 1 10001 root 16900096 Feb  3 08:00`. So they're not owned by root anymore but they still won't allow any user to read them. More information: The backup directory is mounted to the host (not in a Docker volume) in my docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: I haven't tested, but I think if you change the group on the parent directory, `/path/to/dir`, newly created backup files will inherit that group. Getting back to your original question... why does everyone need read-write-execute permissions on the backup files? You can't execute backup files and you certainly shouldn't be writing to them to modify them afterwards.

Comment: The run-as-root answer in the link you provided in the comment above is a hack since it's relying on the host and container both using uid 0 for root so that permissions are "synchronized" between host and container. They aren't actually synchronized, it's a happy accident, and that technique doesn't work when host operating systems don't have a root user with uid 0. Given `docker run -it --rm mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest id` returns `uid=10001(mssql)` a slightly better solution might be to `sudo adduser -u 10001 mssql` on the host and apply correct permissions at the bind point.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have a .NET BackgroundService that is creating backups of the database at scheduled intervals; a customer wants to be able to pull these backups off the host machine and move them to an external server. I suppose I could just have my service just rsync the backups to the server myself; I just didn't want to have to deal with their IT. But I'll do it that way if there's no clean way to set the permissions for the backup file.

Comment: I have the same problem on Sql Server 2019 on linux. Have you found any solution?

Comment: @sDima unfortunately not. I ended up just running a shell script (using the Process class in C#) that changes the permissions for the files after they're created.