# Can not see /var/opt/mssql on Synology Docker

Tags: sql-server, docker, synology

I successfully installed SQL Server in Docker on Synology NAS. I can connect to the database from station. When I do `select * from sys.master_files` I can see that physical_name is `/var/opt/mssql/data`. I need to change rights on that folder but I can not find this folder on Synology.

I am logged in via SSH and when I list folders I can see var but under var are

```
cache   crash     database   db    empty     lib     lock    
log     net-snmp  packages   run   services  spool   state     
synobackup        target     tmp   update
```

no `opt` folder.

In Docker settings, when I map /var/opt/mssql/ to shared directory on Synology, MSSQL does not start.

This is Docker log.

- SQL Server 2022 will run as non-root by default.
- This container is running as user mssql.
- To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.
  /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: Error: The system directory [/.system] could not be created. File: LinuxDirectory.cpp:420 [Status: 0xC0000022 Access Denied errno = 0xD(13) Permission denied]

Anybody can please explain what to do?

Comment: The location is inside the *container* not the host.

Comment: _"I need to change rights on that folder"_ - what makes you think that you need to change permissions in the first place?

Comment: Thank you for answers. Maybe I do not need to change rights, maybe I need to change the owner, I want to test it. I found some informations about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65601077/unable-to-run-sql-server-2019-docker-with-volumes-and-get-error-setup-failed-co  
It looks like that best is to "Setup proper directory owner (mssql)"  
  

It is good to know that /vat/opt/mysql/ is under container but I still do not know how and where to find it. I found that it should be under /var/lib/docker/ but it is not.

Comment: Each container is essentially its own Linux VM with its own file system. Unless you've mounted part of the Docker host file system inside the container's file system you won't be able to interact directly with the container's files and directories. Have you considered opening a terminal session into the container? e.g.: `docker exec -it -u 0 ContainerIdHere /bin/bash`

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand it that much, so I have no idea what terminal session would be good for.
I updated my original question with log from Docker.

Comment: Normally you would setup and configure your container's file system, install and configure extra software, etc., from a `Dockerfile` while building the image that's used to launch a container. If you want to modify a running container you can open a terminal session into it and modify it from a `bash` terminal running inside the container itself. When using the official `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server` images the SQL Server instance is configured to be run using a least-privileged `mssql` user, so the instance has limited access even to the container's own file system.

Comment: Thank you. I can try it. It was test installation, nothing real running yet, so it probably might be easier for me to do clean instal. I hope I can find some detailed informations how to proceed.